# Why is the revision list empty for 225512?

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question, revisions

Why is the [revision list](https://superuser.com/posts/225512/revisions) for Super User question [225512](https://superuser.com/questions/225512/is-there-a-firefox-esnetsion-to-capture-all-the-images-on-a-page-including-thos) empty?

Platform: Firefox 3.6. Windows XP Professional 64-bit, SP 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it wasn't rendered correctly in Firefox. That's mainly because it was never intended to deal with long titles (it was supposed to just say "Return to Question" -- the [changing!] title itself is part of the revision diffs, as [Sathya's](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1828/why-is-the-revision-list-empty-for-225512/1829#1829) screenshot shows).

This will be fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I see (Firefox 3.6.13).

Since the items that should be there are visible off to the right of the screen it could be a CSS issue, caused by the wrapping of the extremely long question title?

[image]

Comment: Seems to be FF specific, looks just like my screenshot on IE7 as well as Chrome (dev) @DMA

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see - What am I missing out ?

[image]

Comment: The table is pushed to the right because of the wrapped title and the div that it's in. Utilizing a "clear:both" on the div for the table would fix it. Not that big a deal.